# Adding Google maps InfoWindow Dynamically Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, google-maps, dynamic, infowindow

I am trying to add a  Google maps InfoWindow Dynamically to Wordpress, this is the code that is currently working with a custom marker I have tried several functions for infowindows but it seems to be breaking and not loading the map. not sure what I might be doing wrong.

this works I just need to add a infoWindow

```
<script type="text/javascript">
              //<![CDATA[

              function load() {
                 var styles = 
                 [
                    {
                      "stylers": [
                        { "lightness": 1 },
                        { "saturation": -76 },
                        { "hue": "#3bff00" }
                      ]
                    }
                  ];


              var lat = <?php echo $lat; ?>;
              var lng = <?php echo $lng; ?>;
              // coordinates to latLng
              var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
              // map Options

              var myOptions = {

              zoom: 14,
              scrollwheel: false,
              center: latlng,
              mapTypeId: 'Styled'
              };

              //draw a map
              var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);
              var styledMapType = new google.maps.StyledMapType(styles, { name: 'Styled' });
              map.mapTypes.set('Styled', styledMapType);
              var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
              position: map.getCenter(),
              map: map,
              icon: '/wp-content/themes/bills_theme/images/pin_bills.png',
              });
              }
              // call the function
              load();
              //]]>

            </script>
```

Comment: I don't see any InfoWindow in your code.  Please add some information about what you tried that didn't work, and where the data that will be displayed in the InfoWindow will come from.

Answer (score 0):

A simple [infowindow](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#InfoWindows) would be (not tested):

```
          //draw a map
          var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);
          var styledMapType = new google.maps.StyledMapType(styles, { name: 'Styled' });
          map.mapTypes.set('Styled', styledMapType);
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: map.getCenter(),
            map: map,
            icon: '/wp-content/themes/bills_theme/images/pin_bills.png',
          });
          var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
          google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function(e) {
             infowindow.setContent("Hello world");
             infowindow.open(map,marker);
          });
          google.maps.event.trigger(marker, "click");
          }
          // call the function
```

Comment: Maybe you can answer my question above then about what you tried (other than the above).  Do you get any javascript errors?  Does the infowindow work if you click on it? Noticed one typo, which I fixed, but should have given you an error.

Answer (score 0):

Just add this code:

```
var contentString = 'put your content here.';
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: contentString,
        position: latlng,
        maxWidth: 200
        });
    infowindow.open(map);
});
```

More info about Info Window you can read [HERE](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#InfoWindows).